# MVC4 Web API Return json propertykey strings with special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

C# do not allows property names with special characters like space etc. Need to have a way to define json objects like this. Any idea ?

```
{
   ".Class1 #Id1" : "Value1"
   ".Class1 #Id2" : "Value2"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the JsonProperty attribute:

```
        public class MyClass
        {
            [JsonProperty(".Class1 #Id1")]
            public string id1 { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(".Class1 #Id2")]
            public string id2 { get; set; }
        }
```